# AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(); kafka when applying Pyspark Imputer on Structured Stream

Tags: pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

AnalysisException: Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start();
kafka

I'm trying to fit Pyspark ML Imputer on Spark Structured Streaming DataFrame to Impute the missing values of specified List of columns from the dataframe.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.ml.feature import Imputer

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Test App").getOrCreate()

kafka_topic_name = "topic1"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "127.0.0.1:29092"

df = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format("kafka") \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
        .option("subscribe", kafka_topic_name) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")\
        .load()


df1=df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")


df_schema_string ="column1 STRING,column2 STRING,column3 DOUBLE"

df2 = df1.select(from_csv(col("value"), df_schema_string).alias("testdata")).select("testdata.*") 


Input_columns=['column3']

imputer =Imputer(strategy='mode', inputCols=Input_columns,outputCols=["{}_imputed".format(c) for c in Input_columns])

model=imputer.fit(df2)
```

Comment: since you are reading from streaming data source(kafka), not sure how that works.. because once you have streaming dataframe, you can use only use writeStream.start() to get the output.